# how to make json array from database records

Tags: angularjs, json

I am making a json array of the objects getting from the database by using angularjs, but only the last record is showing else is not showing.

```
var myApp=angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('Controller',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http) {
$scope.getAllMedicine = function(){
    $http.get('http://localhost:8080/Webapp/webapi/medicine/all').success(function(data){
        for(j=0; j<data.length; j++){
            $scope.medicineList = [{
                "medicineId" : "Id : " + data[j].medicineId,
                "medicineName" : "Name : " + data[j].medicineName,
                "medicinePotency" : "Potency : "+ data[j].medicinePotency,
                "medicinePrice" :"Price : " +data[j].medicinePrice,
                "medicineQuantity":"Quantity : " +data[j].medicineQuantity
            }
            ]
        }
    });
}
}]);
```

Can anybody tell me the mistake that i m making, I shal be thankful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update from

```
for(j=0; j<data.length; j++){
    $scope.medicineList = [{
        "medicineId" : "Id : " + data[j].medicineId,
        "medicineName" : "Name : " + data[j].medicineName,
        "medicinePotency" : "Potency : "+ data[j].medicinePotency,
        "medicinePrice" :"Price : " +data[j].medicinePrice,
        "medicineQuantity":"Quantity : " +data[j].medicineQuantity
    }
    ]
}
```

to

```
var medicineList = [];
for(j=0; j<data.length; j++){
    medicineList.push({
        "medicineId" : "Id : " + data[j].medicineId,
        "medicineName" : "Name : " + data[j].medicineName,
        "medicinePotency" : "Potency : "+ data[j].medicinePotency,
        "medicinePrice" :"Price : " +data[j].medicinePrice,
        "medicineQuantity":"Quantity : " +data[j].medicineQuantity
    });            
}
$scope.medicineList = medicineList;
```

**Problem** - you were setting `$scope.medicineList` for every iteration because of which it was always getting updated with last record.

Answer (score 0):

@nikhil answer is good and it works, but there's a couple of points worth noting.

1. The `$http` legacy promise methods `success` and `error` have been deprecated. Use the standard `then` method instead:

   ```
   $http({
     method: 'GET',
     url: '/yourUrl'
   }).then(
   function successCallback(response) 
   {
      // Things went ok
   }, 
   function errorCallback(response) 
   {
      // Things went bad
   });
   ```
2. The data you are receiving could already be in the JSON format you expect, so you only have to bind it to the scope, like:

   ```
   $scope.medicineList = data;
   ```